# Determining whether an element of a free product of cyclic groups is a commutator.

Tags: group-theory, algorithms, cyclic-groups, combinatorial-group-theory, free-product

> Let $G=C_{n_1}*\cdots*C_{n_k}=\langle a_1,\cdots,a_k\mid a_1^{n_1}=\cdots=a_k^{n_k}=1\rangle$ be a free product of finitely many finite cyclic groups. Given a word $g=g_1\dots g_n\in G$, is there an algorithm to determine whether $g$ is a commutator in $G$, i.e. whether there exist $a,b\in G$ such that $g=aba^{-1}b^{-1}$?

A specific example that I am interested in is $G=C_4*C_4$ and $g=(a_1a_2a_1a_2^{-1})^2$. I believe that this element is not a commutator, but I don't see a simple proof.

The only "test" I currently know of is that $g$ must reduce to the identity in the Abelianization of $G$, but of course, this only says that $g$ is a product of commutators and not necessarily a single commutator.

Comment: Yes there exists an algorithm to do this - more generally there is an algorithm for solving equations over hyperbolic groups. But of course that's overkill and unhelpful - I presume you are looking for a practical algorithm.

Comment: Compare https://arxiv.org/pdf/1304.6312.pdf

Comment: @MoisheKohan I found that paper before posting this question, but it only appears to discuss the _stable_ commutator length, i.e. the growth rate of the commutator length of $g^n$ for large $n$, but I don't believe that tells me anything about the commutator length of a specific $g$.

Comment: @DerekHolt That's good to know. I've never studied hyperbolic groups before so I didn't know that this group was hyperbolic. I did some searching and found a paper (https://arxiv.org/abs/0901.1830) giving an algorithm to solve equations in hyperbolic groups. Is this the algorithm you were referring to? Unfortunately it's a long paper and no computer implementation of the algorithm is given.

Comment: Free products of (finitely many) cyclic groups are virtually free, and virtually free groups are hyperbolic. But I seem to remember that the special case of solving equations over virtually free groups in the most difficult part of the proof for hyperbolic groups. I am not aware of any impmenentations of these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your example, the following (very naive) computation in Magma seems to show that the image of your element $g$ in a finite quotient of $G = C_4 * C_4$ of order $256$ is not a commutator, so it cannot be a commutator in $G$ itself.

```
> G  := Group<x,y | x^4,y^4>;
> P<a,b>:=pQuotient(G,2,3);                                        
> #P;
256
> S:={ (x,y) : x in P, y in P};
>  (a*b*a*b^-1)^2 in S;
false
```

In fact $g$ is the unique element in $[P,P]$ that is not a commutator.

```
> #S;
15
> #DerivedGroup(P);
16
> { x : x in DerivedGroup(P) | not x in S} eq { (a*b*a*b^-1)^2 };
true
```

Comment: Thanks, this is quite helpful. I just used the ANUPQ package in GAP to do a similar computation.